# Homomorphisms Between $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^{100}+2)$ and $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^{501}-2)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

As in title, I want to know ring homomorphisms between $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^{100}+2)$ and $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^{501}-2)$. Can I think $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^{100}+2)$ as $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[100]{-2})$ and $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^{501}-2)$ as $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[501]{2})$? If so, is it true the only homomorphism is the trivial one since if $\phi$ is a homomorphism, we need $\phi(\sqrt[100]{-2})^{100}\in \mathbb{Q}$ but there is no such element in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[501]{2})$?

Comment: @Arthur oops sorry I made mistype

Comment: @AnneBauval no, I am preparing myself for prelim, which I will take next year. This is from past paper.

Comment: Your identifications of the quotient rings are correct although in an exam setting, a proof might be expected. Re "the trivial one," note that while the zero map is certainly an additive and multiplicative map from one field to the other, it might not count as a "homomorphism" (the operative definition might require that $1$ be sent to $1$).  The statement "if $\phi$ is a homomorphism, we need . . ." is also true, but the statement that "there is no such element in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[501]{2})$" would likely also be regarded as requiring proof in an exam setting

Comment: I try to in terms of field extension, the degree is 100, which is not a factor of 501

Comment: @leslietownes yes, I just sketched first the idea since I was not sure. Thanks for your advice, I am trying to fill the gap now.

Comment: @Tim how does that imply the homomorpgism should be trivial?

Comment: @LaurencePW If any nonzero homomorphism between these 2 fields exist,then they are field extensions and we have $501=[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[501]{2}):\mathbb{Q}]=[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[501]{2}):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[100]{-2})][\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[100]{-2}):\mathbb{Q}]=[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[501]{2}):\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[100]{-2})]\cdot 100$

Comment: @Tim Oh I see, that's quite neat. Thank you.